# Drop lower value for "Peer Pressure" badge

Tags: bug, badges, hyperlinks, peer-pressure-badge

Currently the "Go get it" link for the "Peer Pressure" badge contains lower value `-100`:

> [image: peer pressure]

I.e. posts with score below `-100` points will be excluded from the search results.

Use of search pattern `user:me score:..-3` is more correct for this badge.

Worth noting that for "Disciplined" badge there is no upper limit:

> [image: disciplined]

Comment: Don't think it's a bug, they probably believe posts with less than -100 are worth preserving as they're awesome from the other side.... ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard ... in Parallel Universe ...

Comment: How many such posts exist on the network?

Comment: @Oded Do you mean bug reports that developers won't fix due to low importance or anything else? :) I think current bug is so easy to fix that even the time for questions about clarifying the need for fix will be spent more.

Comment: I mean - there's such a small number of such posts (score of less than -100) that I don't see the point. In particular in non-meta sites (where they are even rarer). Might be an easy fix, but I think I would much rather have people look at posts in the range of -3 and lower that those that have been massively downvoted.

Comment: I would also say that calling this a bug is stretching the meaning of the term.

Comment: Agree with @Oded that it's a feature request and not a bug, however it does feel more proper to indeed not put that lower limit. Maybe when the feature was added the search by score required both bottom and upper limits.

Comment: @ShadowWizard badge description contradicts with the search range. Hense this is a bug!

Comment: Huh? It searches within the range of posts that are -3 and lower. It is correct. That there may be more posts than in the searched range doesn't make it incorrect.

Comment: It's not really contradicting, the "Go get it" is just helper method, not the "set in stone" way to get the badge. It's legit to ask to improve the helper method, but if it's not 100% accurate it's not a bug.

Comment: @Oded will I earn badge if I delete post with score `<-100`? If yes - why search string ignore such post? If no - badge description should be corrected.

Comment: @ShadowWizard why `-100`? not `-42` nor `-64`?

Comment: So, what should the limit be? Why not `-100`?

Comment: @alexolut not my idea, but I do understand the motive. 100 is just a high number that it's very unlikely to get there. I don't think whoever did it spent much time on this. (i.e. deciding what number to put.)

Comment: @Oded the request is that there will be no lower limit, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+score%3A..-3 which will show even posts with -1000 score.

Comment: @Oded `-∞` is enough. See ShadowWizard's comment ^

Comment: In my point of view, if a person get a score less than -100, he should not be eligible for this badge

Comment: @SagarV it's a *phenomenal* achievement to get a score less than -100 before the community deletes it.

Comment: @Glorfindel tell this to [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1+score%3A..-100)... ;)

Comment: Really, if a post does reach -100 and it has not been deleted by the OP, those with delete votes, or moderators, there is something important about that post to be worth saving. I honestly think that if a post makes it there, it's not going to be deleted anytime soon

Comment: @ShadowWizard those 2 are horrifying.

Comment: @ShadowWizard because Jeff is a Community itself!

Comment: @alexolut was.... not anymore. :-)